# FusedLocationProviderClient crash with java.lang.NullPointerException: parameter location specified as non-null is null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm using FusedLocationProviderClient in my app and it works fine to get user current location but suddenly I got this crash

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter location
```

here is how I define it inside my activity

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
```

//

```
fusedLocationClient =
                    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
```

// the crash happens on the next code on (addOnSuccessListener)

```
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                    lat = location.latitude
                    lng = location.longitude
                    goToLocationOnMap(LatLng(lat, lng))
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Task.OnSuccessListener` is a [Java class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnSuccessListener) without paramenter-nullability annotation (`@NotNull` or `@Null`). Therefore Kotlin cannot figure out if the type is nullable or not-nullable and the compiler does not complain about unsafe usage of `location` (eg. `location.latitude` instead of `location?.latitude`).

There are 3 possible cases where the location can be `null`, according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known):

- *Location is turned off in the device settings. The result could be null even if the last location was previously retrieved because disabling location also clears the cache.*
- *The device never recorded its location, which could be the case of a new device or a device that has been restored to factory settings.*
- *Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location after the services restarted.*

To sum up: Declare nullability explicitly and handle null-scenario `.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? -> /* null-safe code here */ }`